# Why isn't this field binding in my directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive with 2-way binding on the dataSourceModel scope variable, but for some reason, it is showing as undefined in the directive.  Am I doing something wrong here?

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/LxWMbY9qtDSBUPWNqWV7?p=preview

Code:

Html:

```
<div ng-controller='TestCtrl'>
  <test-directive 
      selected-id='selectedId' 
      data-source-model='workOrderItems'>  <!-- This does not work -->
  </test-directive>
  {{workOrderItems}}  <!-- this works -->
</div>
```

Script:

```
var app = angular.module("testApp", []);

app.controller('TestCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.workOrderItems = 'abcd'; 
    $scope.selectedId = '123';
}]);

app.directive('testDirective',function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
          selectedId: '=',
          dataSourceModel: '='
        },
        replace: true,
        template: "<div></div>",
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
          console.log(scope.selectedId, scope.dataSourceModel);
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`data-` is prefix for custom HTML5 attributes, so the `data-source-model='workOrderItems'` is translated to just `sourceModel` in your directive.

Try renaming your directive attribute to something that doesn't start with data (or reference it in HTML as `data-data-source-model`) and it should work.